# Formatting FreeDOS partition

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning, freedos

I just bought a laptop, and it came with FreeDOS. It has a 500gb drive, and it had a 30gb partition for the freedos, another 30gb partition for I don't know what, and around 400gb free space. I installed Windows 10 on the free space, and I'm trying to have the full drive without partitions. Using the windows tool, I formatted the second partition, but I can't format the one that has the freedos, nor I can extend the Windows one with the one I just formatted. I also turned the Windows partition into the active one. Does anyone know why I can't do this? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: You're asking two separate questions here (formatting a partition & extending your Windows partition).  Please separate them into two questions.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at [gparted](https://gparted.org) to manage your partitions.

As a suggestion, the formatting for any partitions you wish to merge should be the same file system as Windows (NTFS) beforehand if you wish to merge them with a minimum of fuss.

That said, it looks as though the FreeDOS partition holds your boot files (via the "System" designation), so I would be careful tampering with it. It is likely the problems you're having formatting/adjusting your partitions are related to the placement of these files.

**Boot Files**

If you want to move the boot files (assuming you don't want the FreeDOS partition anymore), you may want to look at [EasyBCD](https://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/).

You can currently download the "free" version ("Register") without actually giving any information (just leave the requested fields blank). The option to move boot files is one of the extra tools included with EasyBCD.

*Note: I am assuming EasyBCD should be able to do the job given the FreeDOS partition. However, it may not. Either way, there is always the option (potentially) to shrink the FreeDOS partition to an inconsequential size and leave the boot files where they are (or you can, of course, look for another tool).*

*As an caveat, you will probably want to decide on a boot files strategy **before** adjusting the other partitions.*

Regardless, I would also be highly tempted to back up any data you don't care to lose as well before making any serious adjustments.